# Bitpay Without Credit Card

Tags: privacy, bitpay

I am having trouble finding this information so I would like to ask those who use BitPay:

1. Can you create a BitPay account and spend coins without having a Credit/Debit Card associated with your account?
2. Tying into the first question can you use Bitpay without tying any personal information to your Bitpay account?

Some stores only accept bitcoin via Bitpay but I don't want to create a Bitpay account if it removes my anonymity.

Answer (score 1):

BitPay just payment processor. As buyer in stores you need own only bitcoins in any wallet, exchange or other places. When you make payment to this store, you will need send btc from your wallet or an exchange

In your case BitPay probably help to the store make immediately exchange your btc into usd

Comment: I think I understand that but it doesn't answer my question. I want to know from people who use bitpay if you have  to associate your bitpay account with a credit card or address or real name?

Comment: @NULL yes as a regulated financial company they ask for personal information about their customers. So you need to comply with know your customer/anti-money laundering rules that governments put up.